# How to draw a boundary line on a scatter plot for classifier in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia, scatter-plot

If I want to draw a boundary line to separate two classes which is the result of my classifier. How to draw it?
The picture is the sample, the black line is the boundary I want to draw.
the green points is the boundary points. I want to draw a curve perfectly fit those points. But when I plot those curve, the result is the purple line which is not a curve.

[image]

Comment: It depends on your classifier. In general you need to find points in which the classifier changes its decision.

Comment: Actually I have found the boundary points, but I can't plot a curve perfectly fit those points.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a reproducible example how to do it:

```
using Plots

x = rand(1000)
y = rand(1000)
color = [3 * (b-0.5)^2 < a - 0.1 ? "red" : "blue" for (a, b) in zip(x, y)]

y_bound = 0:0.01:1
x_bound = @. 3 * (y_bound - 0.5)^2 + 0.1

scatter(x, y, color=color, legend=false)
plot!(x_bound, y_bound, color="green")
```

and you should get a plot like:
[image: classification boundary]

The crucial thing here is to make your boundary points ordered (i.e. they must be ordered in the vectors properly so that when you plot a line you connect proper points). In my example I achieved it by varying the y-dimension and calculating the x dimension.

In more complex cases it will be better to use contour plot, e.g.:

```
x = 1:0.1:8
y = 1:0.1:7
f(x, y) = begin
    (3x + y ^ 2) * abs(sin(x) + cos(y)) - 40
end
X = repeat(reshape(x, 1, :), length(y), 1)
Y = repeat(y, 1, length(x))
Z = map(f, X, Y)
contour(x, y, Z, levels=[0], color="green", width=3)

x_s = 7 .* rand(1000) .+ 1
y_s = 6 .* rand(1000) .+ 1
color = [f(a, b) > 0 ? "red" : "blue" for (a, b) in zip(x_s, y_s)]
scatter!(x_s, y_s, color=color, legend=false)
```

and you should get something like:
[image: boundary with contour plot]

However, as you can see this time for the best results it is best to pass scores to `contour` and specify the classification threshold as level.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your TA asked you to conduct a grid search for this question.

The meaning of grid search is not searching over the data point you have, but searching over *whole* coordinate. (I.e. From `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(0,2)` to `(0,100)`, then to `(1,0)`, `(1,1)` and so on.) You may change the distance between each point when you conduct a grid search.

In your case, you need to solve the equation `d_1(X) = d_2(X)`. So what you need to do is to simulate some points (like the above example), then put those points into `|d_1(X) - d_2(X)|`, and pick the points that bring you to a value that is smaller than epsilon (a self-given small number like 0.05 or 0.1). Then use `Plot()` to connect them.

This is not the most efficient way to create the boundary but this is what you learnt in your tutorial. You may also try `contour()`.

Comment: It is a nice assignment :).